# Commutator of a Killing vector and a proportional vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

We have been given the following problem in our GR course. I have been able to develop part of it successfully, but at some point, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly;

**Let $ξ$ be a Killing vector and $s$ be a unitary vector field proportional to $ξ$. Show that $[ξ,s] = 0$.**

I'm using there is a scalar function $f$ such that:
\begin{equation}
s = fξ
\end{equation}
Then, in terms of the Lie derivative:

\begin{equation}
[ξ,s] = L_ξ (fξ)
\end{equation}

This can be developed like:

\begin{equation}
L_ξ (fξ) = (L_ξ (f)) ξ + f (L_ξ ξ)  = (\nabla_ξ f)E + f [ξ,ξ] = (\nabla_ξ f)ξ
\end{equation}

Now comes the part when I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly. I have to show that the directional derivative of f along ξ is zero. What I've reasoned is:

Since f is a scalar, it can be written as:

\begin{equation}
f = v^i w_i
\end{equation}

Where v and w are respectively a vector an a 1-form. This allows me to break my current expression in:

\begin{equation}
 (\nabla_ξ f)ξ = (\nabla_ξ v^i) w_i ξ + (\nabla_ξ w_i) v^i ξ
\end{equation}

And, since I know the metric doesn't change along the Killing vector direction, and v and w are defined within the metric, they shouldn't change either, and the result is then zero.
Is this correct, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You  have been told that $|s|=1$ so $f= |\xi|^{-1}$. Now  compute $\xi^\mu \nabla_\mu |\xi|^{-1}$.

I was able to show that this is  zero in a few lines.